# When "docker-compose up --build", get error: "dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6379: connect: connection refused"

Tags: go, docker-compose, redis

I have a Golang server, a Postgresql database, and Redis. I run everything through docker-compose, the server and the database connect successfully but the server and Redis do not.  Unfortunately, I can't find the reason. I always get an error but Redis is ready to accept the connection. Here is my docker-compose:

````
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: links
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./sql-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - techno
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - redis_test
  app:
    container_name: myapp
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./config/config.yml:/app/config/config.yml
      - ./internal/repository/migration:/app/migration
      - ./links.json:/app/links.json
    networks:
      - techno
      - redis_test
    environment:
      - APP_MODE=DEV
networks:
  techno:
    driver: bridge
  redis_test:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres-vol:```
````

This is how I'm trying to connect:

```
    client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:        "localhost:6379",
        DB:          0,
        DialTimeout: 100 * time.Millisecond,
        ReadTimeout: 100 * time.Millisecond,
    })
```

I've tried changing `localhost:6379` to `redis:6379`, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

We need your full `docker-compose.yml` to understand your context. But correct me if I'm wrong, you also run your Go app in a Docker container right? If that's the case then put both of them inside a same Docker network like:

```yaml
version: "3"

networks:
  example:
    driver: bridge

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - example

  api:
    {api_setup}
    networks:
      - example
```

And your connection should be

connection.go

```golang
client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:        "redis:6379",
        DB:          0,
        DialTimeout: 100 * time.Millisecond,
        ReadTimeout: 100 * time.Millisecond,
    })
```

Comment: Have you tried update the host from "localhost" -> "redis" as above?

Comment: Yes, i changed my port